# How to disable all UITabBarItems when a ViewController is presented modally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've implemented **UITabBar** to my app. Inside ViewController of one UITabBar item, I've shown another ViewController which is **presented modally**. At this stage, I want to disable all the UITabBar item  and re-enable in **willdisappear**.

> Inside the following delegate, if I get the presented modally
>   ViewController then, on comparing I can return without any action. But
>   I'm confused on how to get visible ViewController which is presented
>   modally.
>   Will this approach works?

```
 (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
//HOW CAN I GET HERE VISIBLE VIEWCONTROLLER I.E. PRESENTED MODALLY VIEWCONTROLLER.
}
```

Comment: if you are presenting viewcontroller then it will be above the tabbar I think, please share your code

Answer (score 1):

Disable :

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Enable

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Rather in disabling the tab bar, you can hide tab bar in `viewWillAppear` of presented view controller and again show it in `viewWillDisappear`.*

In `viewWillAppear`:

```
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

In `viewWillDisappear`:

```
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

---

*But if your motive is get visible view controller, you can use the following `UIApplication` extension.*

```
extension UIApplication {

    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}
```